# Некорректно работает  hover

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#icont").mouseover(function () {
        $('#icont').html($('#cont2').html());

    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('#icont').html($('#cont1').html());

    });

    $('#test').hover(function () {
        if ($('#stext').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#stext').show('slow');
            $('#test img').hide('slow');
        } else {
            $('#stext').hide('slow');
            $('#test img').show('slow');
        }
    })
})
```

Очень дергается при наведении.

Answer (score 5):

И `hide`, и `show` выполняются асинхронно, т.е. следующий после вызова код продолжает выполняться, несмотря на то, что функция еще не завершилась. Если хотите чтобы они выполнялись последовательно, установите `hide` в callback для `show`. Подробнее [в доках JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#stext').show('slow')
           .queue(function(){
               $('#test img').hide('slow')
           });
```

Примерно так.